# Program to fit a hyperbola to linear data using least squares (Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm) not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, least-squares

I have a 1D array data which I am trying to model as hyperbola using three parameters. I am trying to implement the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm using the leastsq function from scipy.optimize library. However, my program is getting stuck at an iteration where a number is getting divided by a zero, and I don't understand why.

Some background: The 1D array data are basically lacunarity values for different box sizes. I've generated the lacunarity data from some sound files, [the context to which can be found here.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19174342)

In the algorithm, the least squares function takes three inputs:
(a) initial guess for the three parameters
(b) the x coordinate for the least squares problem - that's basically a 1D array of integers from 1 to 100 in my problem
(c) the y coordinate for the least squares problem - this is the 1D array that stores the lacunarity values. So Lacunarity values are a function of x, where x varies from 1 to 100.

The hyperbola is modeled using three parameters a,b and c as

[image]

The code gives the following error:
 "OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer"

The code:

```
#import
from scipy import *
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import codecs, json
from math import *

# Define your function to calculate the residuals. 
#The fitting function holds your parameter values.  
def residuals(p, y, x):
        err = y-pval(x,p)
        return err

def pval(x, p):
        z = x
        for i in range(100):
                print(x)
                print(x[i]**p[1])
                z[i] = p[0]/(x[i]**p[1])+p[2]
        return z

#read in your data
obj_text = codecs.open('textfiles\CC1.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
b_new = json.loads(obj_text)
data = np.array(b_new)
x = np.arange(1,101)
y = data[1:101]

#guess at initial parameters
A1_0=1.0
A2_0=1.0
A3_0=0.5

#leastsq package calls the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm
pname = (['A1','A2','A3'])
p0 = array([A1_0 , A2_0, A3_0])
plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(y, x), maxfev=2000)

# Now, plot your data
plt.plot(x,y,'xo',x,pval(x,plsq[0]),'x')
title('Least-squares fit to data')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
legend(['Data', 'Fit'],loc=4)

# Your best-fit paramters are kept within plsq[0].
print(plsq[0])
```

According to the error, the value of x changes to 0 at some point in the iteration, and the first parameter a ends up getting divided by zero which gives the error.

To troubleshoot, I printed the values x[i]^b and the array x while executing the code, [and you can see the values here](https://textuploader.com/1535k). I see that the array x is getting modified which shouldn't happen. x should remain a 1D array of natural numbers from 1 to 100 and not get modified in the iteration. I couldn't identify where exactly is the code modifying the array x.

I expect the array x to remain unchanged and the code to print the final three values of the parameters a,b and c.

EDIT: I made some changes to my code after which it worked successfully. Following are those edits incase anyone would be interested:

1. Did not define z as z = x, but rather just defined it as z = np.arange(1,101). The result was that the array x did not change anymore which is what was expected.
2. Changed the datatype of arrays x and y to float using

```py
x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)
```

3. I got stuck once more, at the piece of code which plots the data. I got the errors" 'title' not defined. Similar errors for xlabel, ylabel. So I just removed those lines and just stuck with

```py
plt.plot(x,y,'red',x,pval(x,plsq[0]),'blue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but since you're using exponentiation (`**`), I strongly recommend that you convert all your numbers to `Decimal` beforehand, in order to avoid the precision-loss inherent in floating-point arithmetic on large values.

For example:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100

A1_0=Decimal("1.0")
A2_0=Decimal("1.0")
A3_0=Decimal("0.5")

x = [Decimal(f) for f in x]
y = [Decimal(f) for f in y]
```

Perhaps your zero will "turn up" to be a small value close to zero...

Comment: Thanks, I'll incorporate that. However, the array x in my problem, which contains integers from 1 to 100, isn't suppose to change at all.

Comment: Update: I converted the datatype of all arrays to float by `x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float64)`. Made some other changes to the code and it finally worked!